# Что не правильно в этом коде?

Tags: delphi

Я хотел чтобы окно всё время колебалось вверх - вниз, вверх - вниз. Я добавил этот код в Timer:

```
if f then
  begin
  s:=s+1;
  Form1.Top:=Form1.Top-5;
  end
  else
  begin
    s:=s-1;
    Form1.Top:=Form1.Top+5;
  end;
  if s=5  then f:= False;
  if s=0 then f:= True;
```

У меня при запуске окно просто "поехало"  вниз, а вверх не возвратилось!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такое обращение к булевским типам, это правильный стиль:

```
  if f then
```

Две ошибки в вашем коде:

```
//1.Нехватает начальных значений
 f=true;
 s=0;

 if f then
   begin
     s:=s+1;
     Form1.Top:=Form1.Top-5;
   end
 else
   begin
     s:=s-1;
     Form1.Top:=Form1.Top+5;
   end;
 if s=5  then f:= False;   // 2. здесь нужно s=1, так как s у вас принимает значения: 0 либо 1, но никак не 5.
 if s=0 then f:= True;
```

А вобще в вашем коде переменная s лишняя и самый оптимальный вариант:

```
 f:= True;
 if f then
   begin
     Form1.Top:=Form1.Top-5;
     f:= False;
   end
 else
   begin
     Form1.Top:=Form1.Top+5;
     f:= True;
   end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f:= True;
if f then
      begin
      s:=s+1;
      Form1.Top:=Form1.Top-5;
      f:= False;
      end
      else
      begin
        s:=s-1;
        Form1.Top:=Form1.Top+5;
        f:= True;
      end;
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно сократить и сделать что-то типа

```
form.top:=ifthen(f, form.top+5,form.top-5); 
f:=not f;
```

Answer (score -1):

Что такое **f** ?

Как я понял это булев тип.
Может тогда

```
if f=true then
```

Т.к. не понятно,что вы проверяете... Или я чего-то не понял.
За,что вообще отвечает данный код?
Что должно ехать?

Comment: Ехать должна форма. Насчёт     f не согласен. Если переменная булева типа, то она уже может использоваться как условие. В моём самоучителе так написано!

Comment: Ну тогда понятно,я тут думаю,есть 2 выхода:
1. Попробовать как я сказал (f=true) хотя бы попробовать.
2. Ошибка в остальном коде.

Comment: Я пробовал вообще без остального кода! Самое главное, что нет ошибки! При запуске окно просто "едет" вниз!!!

Comment: Значит у тебя переменная f всегда false - раз она едет только в низ.
А что такое s?